# asp.net api redirect external url

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp.net-web-api, http-redirect

I am trying to find a way to redirect to an external url from our api.
this is the current code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet, Route( "transcribe/{itemNum}/{salUnit}" )]
public IHttpActionResult RedirectToProductPage( string itemNum, string salUnit ) {
  Configuration.Services.GetTraceWriter().Debug( Request, _controllername, $"RedirectToProductPage({itemNum}, '{salUnit}');" );
  GroupClaes.MSSQL.Wiggum.Databases.Distribution dis = new GroupClaes.MSSQL.Wiggum.Databases.Distribution();
  // get productId
  try {
    int productId = dis.Products.Where( x => x.ItemNum == itemNum && x.Active ).Join( dis.PackingUnits, x => salUnit, x => x.Unit, ( inner, outer ) => new {
      inner.Id
    } ).FirstOrDefault().Id;
    Uri url = new Uri($"https://test-eshop.claes-distribution.be/products?page=0&query=&productId={productId}");
    return Redirect( url );
  } catch ( Exception ex ) {
    iTrace.Error( _controllername, ex );
    return InternalServerError();
  }
}
```

a working url to that method is https://api.groupclaes.be/distribution/webshop/data/products/transcribe/1141011100/Z1
I would expect it to redirect me to https://test-eshop.claes-distribution.be/products?page=0&query=&productId=6
It doesn't instead it redirects me to https://api.groupclaes.be/products?page=0&query=&productId=6
so I gues this has to do that it redirect's to another website but I don't know why this is hapening.

In my tracelogs i have the following output:
`[05-07-2018-09-38-25.748 - Info]  System.Web.Http.Request: http://api.groupclaes.be/distribution/webshop/data/products/transcribe/1141011100/Z1;
[05-07-2018-09-38-25.763 - Info]  System.Web.Http.ModelBinding: HttpActionBinding;ExecuteBindingAsync;Model state is valid. Values: itemNum=1141011100, salUnit=Z1;
[05-07-2018-09-38-25.763 - Debug] RAW_API.Controllers.Distribution.ProductsController: RedirectToProductPage(1141011100, 'Z1');;
[05-07-2018-09-38-25.795 - Info]  System.Web.Http.Request: http://api.groupclaes.be/products?page=0&query=&productId=6;
[05-07-2018-09-38-25.795 - Info]  System.Net.Http.Formatting: JsonMediaTypeFormatter;GetPerRequestFormatterInstance;Obtaining formatter of type 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' for type='HttpError', mediaType='application/json; charset=utf-8';`
not exaclty super helpfull but you can also see the redirected request going to the api and giving a 404 error since the page doesn't exist over there.

Comment: in webApi redirect to another website should work as expected. Do you have ActionFilters, OnActionExecuted override, EndRequest event listener, ... that could alter the response after the controller action ?

Comment: I don't, in my web api config the only thing i changed are the formatters (i removed xml in favour of json), I replaced the trace service and enabled cors `new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");` my global.asax file aside from my Application_Start which has 3 lines `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas ();     GlobalConfiguration.Configure ( WebApiConfig.Register );     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes ( RouteTable.Routes );    ` does not contain any other logic